# Random No route matches [GET] "/" error with a working root_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I randomly see a No route matches [GET] "/" error in the logs of an app. Here is the output.

```
[LG53P2]2016-10-25 02:46:20 +0000 severity=FATAL, ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"): FATAL
[LG53P2] actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
[LG53P2] actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
[LG53P2] railties (4.2.7.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
[LG53P2] railties (4.2.7.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:22:in `call'
[LG53P2] actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
[LG53P2] rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
[LG53P2] rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
[LG53P2] activesupport (4.2.7.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
[LG53P2] actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'
[LG53P2] rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
[LG53P2] actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/ssl.rb:24:in `call'
[LG53P2] skylight (0.10.5) lib/skylight/middleware.rb:61:in `call'
[LG53P2] railties (4.2.7.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
[LG53P2] railties (4.2.7.1) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
[LG53P2] puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
[LG53P2] puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:569:in `handle_request'
[LG53P2] puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:406:in `process_client'
[LG53P2] puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:271:in `block in run'
[LG53P2] puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:114:in `call'
[LG53P2] puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:114:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

The app is private and used by a really small number of people and none of the users have experienced this error ( not able to access the root_path ). I never see it outside the logs. I assume this could be a bot doing a scan.

The `routes.rb`file contains the right information:

```
constraints subdomain: "the_subdomain" do    
    scope "(:locale)", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
      root to: 'my_controller/static#home'
    end

    .... other routes

end
```

And the rake routes output seems normal:

`root GET /(:locale)(.:format)  my_controller/static#home`

At this point the app is regularly used and this bug is just a glitch in the logs nothing more. But I think it worth asking!

Any idea about what can cause this error and how or if I can do something about it?

Comment: Which Rails version do you use?

Comment: I will say that if you don't see any strange IP addresses in your log file or php admin login attempts you don't have to worry too much.

Comment: @slowjack2k Rails version is `4.2.7.1`.

Comment: what about redirecting the / to the default home page through the webserver config ? is this done already ? or you have to type mysite.com/path/to/home ?

Comment: I don't see a php or strange admin login attempts (as I already see on other apps). For the IP I'll have to dig a little bit more because the app runs in a container so the IP in the log is always the same. But I could check on the nginx logs as well. Actually I don't worry much, I'm just curious why this is happening.

Comment: Do you see any additional params within your logs for the request causing this error?

Comment: @MostafaHussein you mean adding another route for "/" event if I have root_path already set? I didn't try that, I could but usually the root_path is enough, isn't it?

Comment: @slowjack2k no params are sent, it seems just like a standard get request to the root of the app.

Comment: It looks like your root is defined within a namespace or scope `:locale`, right? Has this namespace restrictions?

Comment: @slowjack2k yes you're right, I'll update the question to reflect that.

Comment: @slowjack2k, I've updated the question. I not sure this is related. The app is multitenant so if you try accessing root_path with a bad locale the router will try to match a tenant name, if the tenant name is not good, you are redirected to root_path (this is working fine without error).

Comment: And you cannot access the app without the right subdomain, it's done at the DNS level. So the router doesn't need to manage users trying to access it without subdomain.

Comment: The `root_path` is restricted to a subdomain. When someone access this app with another domain or via ip, you will expirience this routing error. Is it a wildcard domain and someone can have a typo within the subdomain?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126635/discussion-between-coding-addicted-and-slowjack2k).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the given informations nginx proxies all requests to the Rails app. If the host is accessed directly via IP-Address or custom DNS entries, the first app in line gets the request.
Because the `root_path` is restricted to a subdomain, the given routing error occours.

There are multiple solutions. First, restrict nginx to route only known subdomains to the Rails app. Second, add a route outside the constraint and log such requests with a special controller and action. Third, redirect unknown subdomains to a special site.

Comment: thanks for digging with me trough the chat (see comments of the question). And again for pointing some possible actions to get rid of it!